# Unable to figure out why my zip files are corrupted

Tags: node.js, node-archiver

So I have this utility that makes use of the `archiver` package to generate zip files. The source is a stream of s3 files. I am making use of passthrough stream to upload the archive directly on s3.
The problem is that on production, the generated zip files are randomnly corrupted. when I try to unzip them I get

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

It cannot be issue with multi part archive because the library I am using to generate the zip file doesnt support multi part archives. and I have verified the binary content of the file and the ending bytes look problematic.

Here is the code:

```
'use strict';

const { S3 } = require('./../libs/s3');
const { Upload } = require('@aws-sdk/lib-storage');

const archiver = require('archiver');
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');
const { basename } = require('path');
const mAsync = require('async');

/**
 *
 * This utility can be used to generate a zip file out of a list of s3 files.
 *
 * @param {object} params
 * @param {Array<LinkObject>} params.sourceLinks 
 * @param {LinkObject} params.targetLink
 * @param {string} params.s3Region
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctrsD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctrsD.png) * 
 */
const S3ZipGenerator = function (params, callback) {
  const { sourceLinks, targetLink, s3Region } = params;
  const instance = S3.getInstance({ region: s3Region });

  const archiveStream = archiver('zip');
  archiveStream.on('error', (error) => {
    return callback(error);
  });

  const passthrough = new PassThrough();

  const { bucket, key } = targetLink;
  const putParams = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    Body: passthrough,
    ContentType: 'application/zip'
  };

  const uploadS3Promise = new Upload({
    client: instance,
    params: putParams
  }).done();

  uploadS3Promise.then(() => {
    callback(null);
  }).catch((err) => {
    callback(err);
  });

  // archiveStream.on('end', finishHandler);
  // archiveStream.on('finish', finishHandler);

  archiveStream.pipe(passthrough);

  mAsync.forEachOf(sourceLinks, (source, index, cb) => {
    const s3Params = {
      Bucket: source.bucket,
      Key: source.key
    };
    S3.getInstance({ region: source.region }).send(S3.getObjectCommand(s3Params), (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
      archiveStream.append(response.Body, { name: basename(source.key) });
      return cb(null);
    });
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    // when should we call finalize() actually?
    
    archiveStream.finalize();
  });
};

/**
 * @typedef LinkObject
 * @type {object}
 * @property {string} bucket
 * @property {string} key
 */

module.exports = S3ZipGenerator;
```